# О значении и происхождении выражения "без купюр"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Каково значение "без купюр"? Слышал, что к деньгам происхождение этой фразы отношения не имеет, так ли это?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это от французского [coupure](https://ru.glosbe.com/fr/ru/coupure), у которого более широкий смысл, чем просто "купюра" (банкнота).

Посмотрите по ссылке пятое по счету значение (*вырезанный кусок текста*).

Чтобы не набивать текст самому, (нагло) процитирую ответ [отсюда](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/24963963):

```
Выражение "без купюр" означает, что текст, видео- или аудиозапись публикуется без  
вырезания какой-то или каких-то их частей.
А "купюры" - это и есть вырезанные части. Денежные купюры тоже есть вырезанные из  
листов-заготовок части этих листов.
```

От того же корня происходит и русское слово *купировать*.